# 301 IIS Redirect

Tags: iis, 301-redirect

How do I 301 direct all traffic from domain1.com to domain2.com using IIS?

Also I need domain1.com/page.aspx?params to direct to domain2.com/page.aspx?params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS 6, right-click on the web site defined as domain1.com.  Choose Properties.  Go to the "Home Directory" tab.  One of the choices is "A redirection to a URL".  Choose that, and enter http://domain2.com.  For a 301 redirect, check the box marked "Permanent Redirection".

Comment: It worked except querystring isn't included in the redirect. How can I achieve this?