# make default website url without www

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis

how can i make the default url of my website without the 'www'

if someone enter www.mysite.com if would take him to mysite.com

just like on serverfault.com

i use iis7 and windows server 2008

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set up two separate website entries in IIS, one for www and one without.  Under the directories tab, you will redirect (permanent) the www site to the URL without the www.

similar questions have been asked and [answered](https://serverfault.com/questions/85986/301-iis-redirect/86037#86037) here.

Answer (score 2):

This is normally done via [redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732969%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Most commonly the www dns entry is just a CNAME to the domain entry - although this doesn't necessarily need to be true, just a web server to redirect the request needs to be listening on that IP

Answer (score -1):

First, go to the DNS manager on your server and find your `Forward Lookup Zone` and from the context menu, add a new `Host (A or AAAA)...`.  Leave the first box (host name) blank, but be sure to add the correct ipaddress for the binding.  Click "Okay".

Now, open up IIS7.  Find your website in the list of "Sites" for your webserver.  Right-click on it and select `Edit Bindings...`.  When the "Site Bindings" dialogue appears, click on `Add...`.  Now, select your IP address and port, but in the `Host Name` box, put the name of your website WITHOUT the www at the front.  Click Okay!

That's it!  Now, open up IE and browse to http://mywebsite.com.